# Extracting text between html tags and labelling it with the tag in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to learn how to classify sentences in R.

I have a text file containing sentences in the following format:

```
<happy>
  This did the trick : the boys now have a more distant friendship and David is much happier . 
<\happy>
<happy>
  When Anna left Inspector Aziz , she was much happier . 
<\happy>
```

I do intent to tag the sentences in the following way:

```
dataset$text = When Anna left Inspector Aziz , she was much happier
dataset$label = happy
```

I want to extract the sentence and label them with the emotion. How should I approach this? I know that I should use grouping in regex but I don't know how to do this in R. I am  new to it and learning.

```
rl <- readLines('sentences.txt')
```

Comment: Those backslashes will cause problems; if they were forward slashes, it could be parsed as XML.

Comment: `lapply(split(Filter(nzchar, gsub('<\\\\\\w+>|[<>]', '', trimws(rl))), c(1,1,2,2)), as.list)` I'll let you do the rest

Comment: Is that an actual snippet? (a) it's not HTML (b) it's not valid XML (c) I know of no tag language that uses backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Presently that's badly-formatted XML, as

- XML uses forward slashes in closing tags instead of backslashes. In fact, you can't even read that into R as-is, as it will try to parse `\h` as an escaped character unless you add extra backslashes to escape the backslashes themselves.
- XML needs to be enclosed in a single tag. The problem is much easier to remedy (`paste` on some tags), though.

If, as is not unlikely, your actual data is properly formatted XML, you can use the xml2 or XML packages to parse. I like `purrr::map_df` to iterate over nodes and coerce the results to a data.frame, but you can do the same thing in base R, if you prefer.

```r
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

'<happy>
    This did the trick : the boys now have a more distant friendship and David is much happier . 
</happy>
<happy>
    When Anna left Inspector Aziz , she was much happier . 
</happy>' %>% 
    paste('<sent>', ., '</sent>') %>%    # add enclosing tags
    read_xml() %>% 
    xml_find_all('//text()/parent::*') %>%    # select nodes that are parents of text
    map_df(~list(text = xml_text(.x, trim = TRUE), 
                 emotion = xml_name(.x)))

## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##                                                                                           text emotion
##                                                                                          <chr>   <chr>
## 1 This did the trick : the boys now have a more distant friendship and David is much happier .   happy
## 2                                       When Anna left Inspector Aziz , she was much happier .   happy
```